# Stop .animate() on last image

Tags: javascript, animation, gallery

I'm trying to make a gallery of images to scroll using up/down buttons. So far I go the animation but now I need to make it stop on the first and last image.

This is what I got so far, [jsfiddle.net/sJDMq/47](http://jsfiddle.net/sJDMq/47) (don't mind the buttons, I still need to work on them but they are there, top and bottom red boxes)

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".down_button").click(function () {    
       $(".scroll-products").animate({marginTop: '-=700px'}, 300);
    });

    $(".up_button").click(function () {
       $(".scroll-products").animate({ marginTop: '+=700px' }, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement. `if(!$('.scroll-products').css("margin-top") > max)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have done it this way but just going with what you started with I would just let this JS do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var curIndex = 0;
  var height = 700;
  var maxHeight = 0;
  var allImages = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar_images");
  for(var i=0; i<allImages.length; i++) {
    maxHeight += allImages[i].offsetHeight;   
  }
  var maxIndex = Math.ceil(maxHeight/height);

  $(".down_button").click(function () {
    if(curIndex < maxIndex) {
      $(".scroll-products").animate({marginTop: '-='+height+'px'}, 300);
      curIndex++;
    }
  });
  $(".up_button").click(function () {
    if(curIndex > 0){
      $(".scroll-products").animate({ marginTop: '+='+height+'px' }, 300);
      curIndex--;
    }
  });
});
```

I just updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sJDMq/48/).

Comment: Do you have any questions about my code? Does it help? If it doesn't give you what you are looking for I may be able to help you further. If it does can you accept it?

Comment: Hi, well I don't want to use a var height, because I'm planning on using this for more galleries, and was hoping I could have the last image at the bottom of the div (without showing all that red space). I found this http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/ but I don't really want it to be so complex. Any suggestions? maybe some links?